# the difference between $C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ and $D(\bar{\Omega})$

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there any difference between $C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ and $D(\bar{\Omega})$?

If they are the same, please give a proof of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of these spaces. Usually, functions in $D(\bar \Omega)$ have compact support in $\Omega$. In particular, such functions are zero on the boundary of $\Omega$. Functions in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ do not necessarily have compact support, and can be non-zero on the boundary.

Take $\phi(x)=1$ for all $x\in \Omega$. Then support of $\phi$ is $\Omega$. Hence $\phi$ is not compactly supported, $\phi \in C^\infty(\bar\Omega)$ but $\phi \not\in D(\Omega)$.